# How to set Minutes Component to 0 in UIDatePicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to set Minute componet in UIDatePicker to Zero

Comment: If you're referring to the fact that you can't get it to be all zeros at once in a time interval style picker, that's normal. it forces you to pick a time greater than zero, so minutes or hours need to be > 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is to set the `UIDatePicker` to display only the `00` in minute component, then the answer is **NO**.

You can change the `minuteInterval` property of UIDatePicker---> the minimum value is 1; the maximum value is 30.

Comment: If I do not want to see the minutes column?

Comment: @habibullah U cant do that with uidatepicker. May be right ur own view

Comment: thanks dear, i am using UIPicker with custom NSArray Data{ @"00",@"01", @"02",..... @"23",nil}

Answer (score 2):

You need to truncate the selected date to 60 second intervals. For example:

```
long long truncedDate = [datePicker.date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
truncedDate /= 60;
truncedDate *= 60;
datePicker.date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:truncatedDate];
```

Comment: You probably meant `*=` instead of `*/` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I just set minute component to zero in my DatePicker, by doing this:

`//set current date to datepicker
myDatePicker.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local`

`//create a dateFormatter with "00" instead of "mm" in the minute component:
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:00"
let myStringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: myDatePicker.date)`

`//once we have in String format with minute 00, we convert it to date format to load in DatePicker
let myDateDate = dateFormatter.date(from: myStringDate)
myDatePicker.setDate(myDateDate!, animated: true)`