# UIDatePicker block minute scrolling

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I know that it is not available to set `minuteInterval` on `UIDatePicker` over 30, but is it possible to block minute scrolling on it?

That way the user could only scroll through hours, but the minutes would stay as they are set at start.

Comment: will minutes will be enabled sometime or not? will it be disabled forever?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Minutes Component to 0 in UIDatePicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897518/how-to-set-minutes-component-to-0-in-uidatepicker)

Comment: @HossamGhareeb It should be disabled for the time view is open, another time I open the view it could be possible to set it enabled.

Comment: @HarikrishnanT I don't need the only available minutes to be 00 but just to block them, also the way to set them to 0 after scrolling is not user friendly

Comment: What about using custom UIPickerView for hours and custom UIPickerView for minutes and you can easily enable/disable the minutes picker

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the minutes to 0 or whatever value you want after every change.

```
[self.myDatePicker addTarget:self
                      action:@selector(myAction:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];


- (void)myAction:(id)sender
{
    NSDate *currentDatePickerDate = self.myDatePicker.date;
    NSDate *dateWithoutMinutes = // use NSDateComponents to create a date that's equal to currentDatePickerDate except the minutes
    [self.myDatePicker setDate:dateWithoutMinutes animated: NO];
}
```

But maybe you are better off to just show a `UIPickerView` to select the hour and show the minutes as constant right to the side of it.

Setting `-[UIDatePicker minuteInterval]` to 60 might also do what you want.